# After upgrade to CiviCRM 5.48.0, all submissions say "Mailing cannot be sent. There are missing or invalid fields (subject,name,from_name,from_email

Tags: civimail

After upgrading from CiviCRM 5.46.x to 5.48.0, any attempted mailing creates an error after clicking "Submit Mailing" with "Mailing cannot be sent. There are missing or invalid fields (subject,name,from_name,from_email,body)." Those fields are clearly filled in in the mailing, and when submitting a test mailing, it goes through, and the test mailing is sent and delivered.

Anyone else experiencing this, and/or any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: I'm getting the same.  Have you found any more clues?

Comment: If you go to the Extensions listing, what version of Flexmailer do you have?

Comment: I had the same issue, but it started working again after I enabled the FlexMailer extension.

Comment: See https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/mail/-/issues/107

Answer (score 7):

I found the solution: Flexmailer is now part of the standard distribution. With Drupal 7, Flexmailer is now located under sites/all/modules/civicrm/ext
I had an older version of Flexmailer under sites/default/files/civicrm/ext which caused the problem.
To remove it, I had to first disable mosaico, than remove the Flexmailer files, than uninstall Flexmailer (ignore the warning), refresh the list (it then appears again with the right path), and finally reinstall and enable Flexmailer, and re-enable Mosaico.

Comment: If you have command line access then: `cv dis flexmailer mosaico`, `rm -rf old_flexmailer`, `cv en flexmailer mosaico`

Comment: The problem appears to be that Flexmailer is not enabled by default as part of the upgrade 5.46.x -> 5.48.0. Enabling it has to be done manually.

Comment: There seem to be two causes: either flexmailer is not enabled as in your case & reswild's, or an old version of flexmailer is enabled as in mine & Oliver's.

Answer (score 4):

Per the comment above: Flexmailer version was 5.48.0, but it was not installed. Installing the extension fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with a build in Joomla -

If I disable Mosaic - stop flexmailer and uninstall and reinstall via the extension menu I still get the same error -

Suggestions ?

Thanks

Comment: This will give you the fix for this - edit mailling.php insert 1 line and add 10 https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/23142/commits/3ce48467c714619ada9e5ae5e4479bffe52385ea#diff-6ff1f11b650b0ccf8dca9b5981a37ba8e5541c58f7a6c6ab320ac6ea427ce6d1

Answer (score 0):

One other possibility here...

I have seen this CiviCRM error message "Could not identify any recipients. Perhaps your test group is empty..." when email attachments are a combined size of >10MB and get rejected by the sending server.

If you check the logs you should see a more helpful error message that might throw more light on this rather generic and confusing Civi message.